# How to get mean, median, mode from unique values in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, multiple-columns

could you help me how to get do as said in Title?
I just started learning python recently.

I have a data set of SalePrice and MSZoning.

```
    MSZoning    SalePrice
0   RL  208500
1   RL  181500
2   RL  223500
3   RL  140000
4   RL  250000
... ... ...
1455    RL  175000
1456    RL  210000
1457    RL  266500
1458    RL  142125
1459    RL  147500

house = df[['MSZoning', 'SalePrice']]
```

house

MSZoning has multiple uniqueness such as RF, RL, RM, C (all), FV, RH. The question is, how can I get the mean, median, and mode of SalePrice which has RH, RF, and RL tag in another column? I can't summon them as list no matter how I tried. I have looked around, haven't found any case like this yet.

It will be appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: for unique values **mode** will be meaningless...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think finally understand how to do this.

```
df['column I want to use its values'].loc['column that I use as pivot for filter' == 'category used']
```

Using dataset by Daweo for example, I want to get make a list of A's value and put it in a variable:

```
A = df['price'].loc['zone' == 'A']
```

After getting A, I can just do this to get mean and median:

```
A.mean() #getting mean
np.median(A) #getting median
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it looks like task for [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html). Let do it on toy data:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'zone':['A','A','B','B','B','C','C','C'],'price':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,20]})
print(df.groupby('zone').median())
```

Output:

```
      price
zone
A       1.5
B       4.0
C       7.0
```

If you replace last line with:

```
print(df.groupby('zone').mean())
```

Output will be:

```
      price
zone
A       1.5
B       4.0
C      11.0
```

However there is not `.mode()`, but anyway before trying to get mode you need to decide what should happen if there is more than one most popular value, for example what is mode of `[2,4,2,4]`?

Comment: Hi thanks for sharing your take. If we're doing it that way, I can only get the result by print it out. If I want to make a array out of it or list etc, do you think it's possible?

Comment: @RG182: yes, what I print are just `DataFrame`s, so you can take column from it and convert to `list` for example you might do `medians_list = df.groupby('zone').median()['price'].tolist()`

Comment: I see, I managed to get the summary of each category and make it into a list. Thanks a bunch. I'd like to know again, could I be more specific? Like could I get a list/array from that group i.e. I want to make all values of 'A' in the df? Result should be 'A':[1,2]. something like this

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DataFrame.agg` for applying multiple functions and return the output in a dictionary,

```
output = df.groupby('zone')['price'].agg(['mean', 'median']).to_dict('index')

{'A': {'mean': 1.5, 'median': 1.5},
 'B': {'mean': 4.0, 'median': 4.0},
 'C': {'mean': 11.0, 'median': 7.0}}
```

​